# What better way ? Create own event or use afterSave/beforeSave methods?

Tags: magento

I need to handle event changing Base currency (admin panel). But magento 2 doesn't have one. So i have two options to solve this.

- Create own event and observer for
- Create plugin for afterSave method

  ```
  <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Currency\Base">
                  <plugin name="namespace_config_currency_plugin"
                  type="Namespace\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Currency\Plugin"
                  sortOrder="10"
                  disabled="false"/>
  </type>
  ```

I wonder which way is more appropriate or less expensive for system. 
Thanks!

Comment: You've tagged Magento 1.9, yet plugins are a feature of Magento 2 - are you sure that's correct?

Comment: oh, i have already fix it